# Do variadic templates work correctly with current compilers?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, visual-studio-2013, mingw

I tried to implement a simple tuple according to c++11 variadic templates feature like that:

```
template <class Head, class... Tail>
class tuple;

template <class Head>
class tuple<Head>
{
public:
    tuple(Head h) : m_h( h ) {}

    tuple(tuple const & rhs)
    : m_h( rhs.m_h ) {}

    template<class T>
    tuple(tuple<T> const & rhs)
    : m_h( rhs.head() )
    {}

    Head head() const
    {
        return m_h;
    }
private:
    Head m_h;
};

template <class Head, class... Tail>
class tuple : private tuple<Tail...>
{
public:
    typedef tuple<Tail...> inherited;
    tuple(Head h, Tail... tail)
    : inherited(tail...), m_h( h )
    {}

    Head head() const
    {
        return m_h;
    }

    inherited &
    tail()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    inherited const &
    tail() const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename... Values>
    tuple(tuple<Values...> const & rhs)
    : inherited( rhs.tail() ),
      m_h( rhs.head() )
167:    {}
private:
    Head m_h;
};
```

And tried to use it as follows:

```
    tuple<int, double, char> tpl(0, 3.3, 'a');
175:    tuple<long, float, short> tpl2 = tpl;
```

This resulted in:

```
test.cpp(167) : error C2664: 'tuple<short,>::tuple(const tuple<short,> &)' : can not convert argument 1 from 'const tuple<char,>' to 'short'
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
test.cpp(167) : see reference to function template instantiation 'tuple<float,short>::tuple<double,char>(const tuple<double,char> &)' being compiled
test.cpp(167) : see reference to function template instantiation 'tuple<float,short>::tuple<double,char>(const tuple<double,char> &)' being compiled
test.cpp(175) : see reference to function template instantiation 'tuple<long,float,short>::tuple<int,double,char>(const tuple<int,double,char> &)' being compiled
test.cpp(175) : see reference to function template instantiation 'tuple<long,float,short>::tuple<int,double,char>(const tuple<int,double,char> &)' being compiled
```

with Visual Studio 2013 and in:

```
c:\Users\achernyaev\Documents\test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c:\Users\achernyaev\Documents\test.cpp:175:35: error: conversion from 'tuple<int,double, char>' to non-scalar type 'tuple<long int, float, short int>' requested tuple<long,float,short> tpl2 = tpl;
                              ^
```

with MinGW's g++ 4.8.1

Question: Is this code really malformed or maybe this feature isn't supported good enough yet?

Best regards, Alexander.

Comment: Please improve your title. The answer to the title is obviously yes.

Comment: Problem: *Order of the classes*.. Switch the two classes.. Put the one with the variadic template before the one without it. That'll fix the specialization issue.. as shown here: http://ideone.com/SbMLtK

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. That's incorrect markup that I've corrected - there is a forward declaration before more specialized one and in the beginning I had more specialized one implemented right after the variadic version but results were the same.

Comment: A shorter program that seems to have the same problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01ab47f71de35bbe  I can't see why it wouldn't be well-formed.

Comment: @aschepler: Look at the error clang gives O.O http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ad41ad6497eeacd `candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Values = <>]: too few template arguments for class template 'tuple'`

Comment: Oddly, Visual Studio 2013 compiles this aschepler's code fine: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/nkcV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistake in the code: Here is a corrected one:

```
template <class ...> class tuple; // declaration as a multivariate template.

template <class Head>
class tuple<Head>
{
private:
    Head m_h; 
public:
    tuple(Head h) : m_h( h ) {}

    tuple(tuple const & rhs)
    : m_h( rhs.m_h ) {}

    template<class T>
    tuple(tuple<T> const & rhs)
    : m_h( rhs.head() )
    {}

    Head head() const
    {
        return m_h;
    }
};

template <class Head, class... Tail>
class tuple<Head, Tail...> : // explicitly write the partial specialization. 
   private tuple<Tail...> 
{
private:
    Head m_h;

    typedef tuple<Tail...> inherited;
    tuple(Head h, Tail... tail)
    : inherited(tail...), m_h( h )
    {}

    Head head() const
    {
        return m_h;
    }

    inherited &
    tail()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    inherited const &
    tail() const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename... Values>
    tuple(tuple<Values...> const & rhs)
    : inherited( rhs.tail() ),
      m_h( rhs.head() )    {}
};
```

Comment: There was no need to declare `m_h` before using it.. The only problem OP had was declaring the specialization before the base.. http://ideone.com/7R5rSy  The base being the variadic template class.

Comment: This has no relation to the problem itself. The variadic forward declaration comes before the specialization.

Comment: And yes - the code you published is exactly my original version I tried to use and yes - it compiles good. But the problem comes with `tuple<long, float, short> tpl2 = tpl;` statement when template ctor must come into play.

Comment: Yep. Sorry dude @hivert. Your code compiles good. I just missed the fact you specialized tuple<Head, Tail...>.

Answer (score 0):

Deduction fails for your converting constructor:

```
template<typename... Values>
tuple(tuple<Values...> const & rhs)
: inherited( rhs.tail() ),
  m_h( rhs.head() )
{}
```

but succeeds when defined as:

```
template<typename H, typename... T>
tuple(tuple<H, T...> const & rhs)
: inherited( rhs.tail() ),
  m_h( rhs.head() )
{}
```

I believe deduction fails when trying to match the parameter pack `Values` up with the non-pack parameter `Head` of the `tuple` template, per C++11 §14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]/10:

> If the parameter-declaration corresponding to P<sub>i</sub> is a function parameter pack, then the type of its declarator-id is compared with each remaining parameter type in the parameter-type-list of A. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the function parameter pack. During partial ordering (14.8.2.4), if A<sub>i</sub> was originally a function parameter pack:
>
> - if P does not contain a function parameter type corresponding to A<sub>i</sub> then A<sub>i</sub> is ignored;
> - otherwise, if P<sub>i</sub> is not a function parameter pack, template argument deduction fails.

In any case, you could simplify the class by making the empty tuple the base case for the recursion, and defining the whole shebang as:

```
template <class...> class tuple {};

template <class Head, class... Tail>
class tuple<Head, Tail...> : private tuple<Tail...>
{
public:
    typedef tuple<Tail...> inherited;
    
    tuple(Head h, Tail... tail)
    : inherited(tail...), m_h( h )
    {}

    Head head() const
    {
        return m_h;
    }

    inherited &
    tail()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    inherited const &
    tail() const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename... T>
    tuple(tuple<T...> const & rhs)
    : inherited( rhs.tail() ),
      m_h( rhs.head() )
    {}

private:
    Head m_h;
};
```